# Where will the database be created in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
mongos.connect("mongodb://localhost/Company")
```

On executing the above command as per the document if Company database exits then it will be connected to the nodejs or else database will be created and then connection is made.

My question is where will this newly created database exist in mongodb data folder or nodejs application folder

Comment: I think u  are expecting an MONGO UI.. Install RoboMongo nad then it will show u the database details clearly..

Comment: It will sit in the MongoDB data folder

Comment: To be a bit more specific: it will sit in the data folder of the primary shard which the database got assigned to. You can find out which the primary shard for the database is by connecting to a `mongos` instance using the mongo shell and issue `sh.status()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your application is connecting to localhost where you have MongoDB server running on the default port (27017). If you are connected to a MongoDB cluster using a mongos process you will have to see where the mongod (database process itself) is/are running. Let's take the simple case where your mongod is running locally.

So I expect you have started your MongoDB instance with all default values, the "database files" are created in /data/db ( \data\db  ).

This means that in your case, you should see the "Company" db files in this folder, something like :

> /data/db/Company.0
>
> /data/db/Company.ns

Let's now give you more informations about this:

When you start your database you start a "mongod", that use a parameter named dbpath (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath ) that is defaulted to /data/db

You can override it to any existing folder to adapt to your environment.

So nothing is "created" inside your application, everything in done at the"mongodb" (database) level.

Comment: i checked its not present in the folder

Comment: 1. Could you confirm that you are running the database locally? 2. Try to insert document into your DB (it is only created once you have done something with it) 3. Do you have access to Mongo Shell? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/